# repeat n times an element between 2 dates and indicate the dates right next to it

Tags: date, google-sheets, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

How can I repeat an element between 2 dates and indicate the dates

Input values:

| ID | Begin | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ST00 | May 15 2022 | May 15 2022 |
| TE01 | May 23 2022 | May 25 2022 |
| TO01 | May 16 2022 | May 19 2022 |

Expected output:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| ST00 | May 15 2022 |
| TE01 | May 23 2022 |
| TE01 | May 24 2022 |
| TE01 | May 25 2022 |
| TO01 | May 16 2022 |
| TO01 | May 17 2022 |
| TO01 | May 18 2022 |
| TO01 | May 19 2022 |

What I am doing right now :

in E2

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY( REPT(A2:A&"~", if(A2:A="",,C2:C-B2:B+1)),,9^9), "~"))))
```

in F2 (and dragging below)

```
=countif(E$2:E2,E2)
```

in G2

```
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(E2:E,A:B,2,0)+F2:F-1))
```

[image]

**Is there a way to do whitout column F?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(C2:C, B2:B)>=SEQUENCE(1, 1000, ), 
 IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&"×"&TEXT(B2:B+SEQUENCE(1, 1000, ), "mmm dd e")), )), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

[image]

faster:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(C2:C, B2:B)>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(C2:C-B2:B+1), ), 
 IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&"×"&TEXT(B2:B+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(C2:C-B2:B+1), ), "mmm dd e")), )), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

Comment: whaou, thx Cooper ! I tried with sequence but didn't find any solution. Great!

Comment: I removed format to keep values in column F. Indeed with adjusted sequence it is faster.

Comment: there is fun way to do these that involves using an extra column in the query that you compare against...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yBW66GTyY7tlxii7IHy1lCRob2SJ-aFOuqyUBUyOA-E/edit#gid=820953330

Answer (score 1):

A similar formula to @player0's but I like to use the end column as an "extra" column in the constructed array for the query to compare against.

Here's a [sample sheet created specifically to solve this problem](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yBW66GTyY7tlxii7IHy1lCRob2SJ-aFOuqyUBUyOA-E/edit#gid=820953330) where this formula can be found in A2 on the tab called 'output'

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Data!A2:A&"|"&Data!B2:B+SEQUENCE(1,MAX(Data!C2:C-Data!B2:B),0)&"|"&Data!C2:C),"|",0,0),"select Col1,Col2 where Col2<=Col3"))
```